# Find $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-2| < \delta$ implies $|x^2+2x-18| < \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Find $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-2|  < \delta$ implies $|x^2+2x-18| < \frac{1}{4}$.

I have been having trouble with this question from my Analysis class because $f(x)$ doesn't factor. Here is the first scratch work I did attempting to find a suitable $\delta$:

Let $\delta_1 =1$. Then $|x-2| < \delta \implies -1 < x-2<1 \implies 3 < x+2 < 5$. Hence $|x+2|<5$.

We want $|x^2+2x-18|< \frac{1}{4}$. This is the same as:
$$\frac{-1}{4} < x^2+2x-18 < \frac{1}{4}$$
$$-1 < 4x^2+8x-72 < 1$$
$$71 < 4x^2+8x < 73$$
$$71 < 4x(x+2) < 73$$
$$|4x(x+2)|=|4x||x+2| \leq |4x| \cdot5 < 73$$
$$|4x| < \frac{73}{5}$$

I got stuck here. In the other practice problems we did I always ended up with something like $|x-a|<...<...$ so I'm not sure what went wrong? I do not see how to factor $x^2+2x-18$ into something that utilizes $(x-2)$.

Comment: Looks impossible to me. If $x=2$ then the left hand side of the inequality is $|2^2 + 2 \cdot 2  - 18| = 10$ but $10 \not< \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: I was thinking the same. This is the exact problem from the book Analysis with an Introduction to Proof by Lay. Must be a typo, it would make a LOT more sense if it were $|x^2+2x-8| < \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: I think you are on the right track about correcting that typo.

Comment: $|x^2+2x-18| < \frac{1}{4}$ has the solutions $ -1 -\frac{\sqrt{77}}{2} < x < -1 -\frac{\sqrt{75}}{2}$ or   $ -1 +\frac{\sqrt{75}}{2} < x < -1 +\frac{\sqrt{77}}{2}$.  But $2$ and its immediate neighbourhood are not in either interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=|x^2+2x-18|$. For all $\delta>0$, $|2-2|<\delta$ but $f(2)=10\geq\frac{1}{4}$. So no matter which value you pick for $\delta$ there is a $x$ ($2$) that wont satisfy $|x^2+2x-18|<\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, requiring $0<|x-2|<\delta$ leads to similar results.

Comment: Yes I do see this now. My professor confirmed it is a typo in the textbook. The correct number in the function was 8, not 18.